# can I user React Native SDK with expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I created an Expo app with "Expo init myapp" Now I am trying to integrate a react Native SDK feature in it, This sdk feature include me to add some custom code to the android.xml files and some other files, Can this work out?

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not use Bare React Native with Expo because Expo does not have android and ios native folders that are handled by Expo itself. However, you can use Expo with React Native Bare CLI

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research on this out of curiosity and I found that you can convert your Expo project to React Native Bare CLI after that you'll have android and ios folder for the native configuration you can try it out if you want however I would recommend taking backup of your current code in case anything goes wrong or does not work properly (I just did research I haven't tried it my self fully I ejected 1 app and it created native folders but didn't have time to run code)

use `expo eject` to detach the project

Docs are given [here](https://%20https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/?redirected#instructions)

Sidenote (that I found on other sourcce): It doesn't create the folder structure like when done using react-native init... It creates android & ios folders respectively.

I haven't checked it very thoroughly you may need to do some configuration before you can run your app

Comment: this is something that looks a bit confusing to me, while still using the expo project yesterday I used "npm install react-native-appodeal --save" it created a folder "react-native-appodeal" and the folder contain android and "AndroidManifest.xml" file, I was told to edit the "AndroidManifest.xml" which was present under the newly created folder. I was wondering if to edit the file under the new folder or the general android folder that comes with react-native init.?
Here is the documentation, I am trying to get started with appodeal
"https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-appodeal"

Answer (score 0):

Expo distinguished between two types of workflows, managed and bare. The managed workflows does not allow you to access any native files. The configurations are handled in the app.json file. In contrast, the bare workflow give you access to all native files.

Hence, the answer is - yes, it can work out, but the bare workflow must be used. Documentation on how to use the bare workflow can be found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/).

Comment: @enrich, please how can I contact you? I just wanna ask some few questions about react native sdks, I have been using expos.